# Make Annotation clickable in Annotation Overlay Effect with CSS3 by Tympanus

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, effect

I came across this very neat annotation overlay effect: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/05/14/annotation-overlay-effect-with-css3/

You can see a live demo here: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3AnnotationOverlayEffect/ (you will need to click on the picture there to see the effect)

I am trying to make the text within annotation `<span>` clickable with some external link, like:

```
<span><a href="http://google.com">Easy Theme Options</a></span>
```

but it doesn't work... whenever I click on the annotation, it transitions back to full size image.

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work, as you see in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cJz2Y/).

The problem is that the checkbox is always over the spans. And because all the checkbox and the spans are positioned absolute, changing the `z-index` wouldn't work! The only way I found it to work with only CSS (by not changing to much) is by messing with the `pointer-events` property and the `<div class="ao-annotations">`'s `z-index`. (`z-index` is layered within an element. Because the annotations `<div>` and the checkbox are both in `<div class="ao-preview">`, changing the `<span>` `z-index` wouldn't work.

I did the following:

I set the z-index of the `div.ao-annotations` higher than the `input.ao-toggle`. This results to not being able to click on the input, so not being able to toggle.

To solve this I added `pointer-events: none` to the `<div class="ao-annotations">`. Now the result is the same, but the `<span>`s are now positioned on top of the input.

To be able to click on the `<span>`s I added this CSS:

```
input.ao-toggle:checked ~ .ao-annotations span{
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

This results to only being able to click on the `<span>`s when the checkbox is checked.

Summary:

```
.ao-annotations {
    z-index: 20;
    pointer-events: none;
}

input.ao-toggle {
    z-index: 10;
}

input.ao-toggle:checked ~ .ao-annotations span{
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

I am very sad to say this only works in IE11 (and all the other browsers)... So you'd probably have to 'hack' with Javascript or rebuild the HTML / CSS.

I hope you can build on this!

Comment: You bet I will build on this, you are my hero!! This is exactly what I was looking for!